# How to prevent TreeView rename from making a duplicate

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes

I've seen lots of posts asking a question similar to this, but none seem to answer the question. I have a TreeView of vendors like this:

```
Soda
    Regular
        SmallCan
        SmallBottle
    Diet
        SmallCan
Water
    Regular
        EcoBottle
```

I created a context menu that allows the user to rename the selected node, but cannot find a way to enforce that if it makes a duplicate node name, either the change is refused or the node text is reverted to the previous value. This is the context change event and the method to handle the enforcing:

```
private void contextMenuRename_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    restoreNode = treProducts.SelectedNode;
    treProducts.LabelEdit = true;
    if (!treProducts.SelectedNode.IsEditing)
    {
        treProducts.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
    }
    enforceNoTreeDuplicates();
}


private void enforceNoTreeDuplicates()
{
    nodeNames.Clear();
    if (treProducts.SelectedNode.Level != 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treProducts.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes)
        {
            nodeNames.Add(node.Text);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treProducts.Nodes)
        {
            nodeNames.Add(node.Text);
        }
    }
    int countDuplicates = 0;
    foreach (string nodeName in nodeNames)
    {
        if (restoreNode.Text == nodeName)
        {
            countDuplicates++;
        }
        if (countDuplicates > 1)
        {
            treProducts.SelectedNode = restoreNode;
        }

    }
}
```

However, the BeginEdit() doesn't seem to run if the enforceNoTreeDuplicates() method is in there. Is there a better way to handle the editing of the selected node or is there something wrong with the enforceNoTreeDuplicates() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would use the AfterLabelEdit for that, which has an option to cancel the edit:

```
void treProducts_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e) {
  foreach (TreeNode tn in e.Node.Parent.Nodes) {
    if (tn.Text == e.Label) {
      e.CancelEdit = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added treProducts_AfterLabelEdit += new LabelEditEventHandler(treProducts_AfterLabelEdit); but get the error "No overload for 'treProducts_AfterLabelEdit' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.LabelEditEventHandler'" Any suggestions for fine-tuning the event handler. Thank you.

Comment: @Phoenix14830 It's a NodeLabelEditEventArgs.  You can use a short hand: `treProducts.AfterLabelEdit += treProducts_AfterLabelEdit;`